# How do I go about making a discord bot in python that alerts me when a specific person joins a specific voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I've been developing a bot for a while now and I want the bot to notify or alert me when a specific member of the server joins a specific voice channel in the server.
I know that there needs to be specification of the channel_id and the user_id but how do i go about writing it. I want the bot to, either direct message me or like, mention me in a specific channel to alert me when that someone joins that specific channel. Does it make sense? It's a very specific command for a very specific purpose. How do I go about adding that to my bot??

I watched a couple tutorials but I never seem to find what I was expecting.

Comment: For the next time, please add what you have tried to show that you did try by yourself before asking / make it easier to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `on_voice_state_update` event that is called when a `Member` changes their `VoiceState`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member : discord.Member, before : discord.VoiceState, after : discord.VoiceState):
    member_id = 123456789                                               # The id of the specific member
    channel_id = 987654321                                              # The id of the specific voice channel
    owner_id = 192837465                                                # The id of the user (you) the bot has to dm when the specific member join the specific channel
    
    if member.id != member_id: return                                   # Continue only if the member that triggered the event is the specific member
    if not after.channel or channel_id != after.channel.id: return      # Continue only if the channel that the member is conected to is the specific voice channel
    if before.channel and before.channel.id == after.channel.id: return # Continue only if the member that triggered the event wasn't already connected to the specific voice channel
    
    owner = bot.get_user(owner_id)
    await owner.send('The specific member has connected to the specific voice channel')
```

**Notes:**

1. I might have missed some specific case you may want to take into account. Check if you need to monitor something else
2. Your bot needs to have the [voice_states intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.voice_states) enable

**References:**

1. [on_voice_state_update event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)
2. [VoiceState class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState)